# Want to create where where when paddle_a hits any of the blocks, then turtle.bye()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, game-development, python-turtle

I'm having trouble creating a collision where if the white block(paddle_a) hits any of the red blocks the game ends. (would also like to know how to make a collision where if the white block hits something it acts as a wall/is a wall.

```
# Game creation
#Pong game test

import time
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("Black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=800)
wn.tracer(0)

# paddle a
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(0, -300)



# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y += 30
    paddle_a.sety(y)
def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -= 30
    paddle_a.sety(y)
def paddle_a_fun():
    paddle_a.forward(20)
def paddle_a_dow():
    paddle_a.backward(20)

# Keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_fun, "d")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_dow, "a")

# red blocks
block_a = turtle.Turtle()
block_a.speed
block_a.shape("square")
block_a.color("red")
block_a.penup()
block_a.goto(0, 0)


block_b = turtle.Turtle()
block_b.speed
block_b.shape("square")
block_b.color("red")
block_b.penup()
block_b.goto(0, 100)

block_c = turtle.Turtle()
block_c.speed
block_c.shape("square")
block_c.color("red")
block_c.penup()
block_c.goto(0, 300)

block_d = turtle.Turtle()
block_d.speed
block_d.shape("square")
block_d.color("red")
block_d.penup()
block_d.goto(0, -200)

block_e = turtle.Turtle()
block_e.speed
block_e.shape("square")
block_e.color("red")
block_e.penup()
block_e.goto(0, -100)

block_f = turtle.Turtle()
block_f.speed
block_f.shape("square")
block_f.color("red")
block_f.penup()
block_f.goto(0, 200)

block_g = turtle.Turtle()
block_g.speed
block_g.shape("square")
block_g.color("red")
block_g.penup()
block_g.goto(0, 100)

block_h = turtle.Turtle()
block_h.speed
block_h.shape("square")
block_h.color("red")
block_h.penup()
block_h.goto(0, 1)




# consequences
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Border checking
    if paddle_a.ycor() > 380:
        turtle.bye()

    # Collision with red blocks
    for collision in block_h:
        if collision.distance(paddle_a) < 20:
            time.sleep(1)
            paddle_a.goto(0, 0)
            paddle_a.direction = "stop"
```

Thought of different things, tried all, didn't work. just need help am new to collision coding and game development In general.

Comment: "Thought of different things, tried all, didn't work" isn't very helpful. Please share these attempts. We're not interested in _that_ you tried; we're interested in _what_ you tried. Thanks. As an aside, `while True:` just slams the CPU as hard as possible. Not a good event loop--prefer `ontimer`. `for collision in block_h:` doesn't make sense; `turtle`s aren't iterable. You should see an error when you run this code (please post it in your question if you do get errors so everyone is on the same page).

Comment: I'd put those red blocks in a list so you can loop over them and compare collision against the player. Otherwise, you have to type out each collision with `_a`, `_b` etc specifically, which isn't [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (or use dynamic variable string hacks, but please don't do that).